# Why are my variables reporting as "undeclared identifier" when compiling?

Tags: c, variables, scope

I have the following code:

```
       for(int iY=0;iY<(Height-YRemainder);iY=iY+16);
        {
            for(int iX=0;iX<(Width-XRemainder);iX=iX+16);
            {
                if(Operation==BLACKNESS)
                {
                    Operation = WHITENESS;
                    PatBlt(DeviceContext, iX, iY, 16, 16, Operation);
                }
                else
                {
                    Operation = BLACKNESS;
                    PatBlt(DeviceContext, iX, iY, 16, 16, Operation);
                }
            }
            if(Operation == BLACKNESS)
            {
                Operation = WHITENESS;
                PatBlt(DeviceContext, Width-XRemainder,iY,16,16,Operation);
            }
            else
            {
                Operation = BLACKNESS;
                PatBlt(DeviceContext, Width-XRemainder, iY, 16, 16, Operation);
            }


        }
```

When I compile, I get undeclared identifiers reported against each PatBlt for iX and iY.  Am I misunderstanding how the scope of each variable is working here or have I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have semi colons at the end of the for statements which turns them into single line statements:

```
for(int iY=0;iY<(Height-YRemainder);iY=iY+16);
```

becomes

```
for(int iY=0;iY<(Height-YRemainder);iY=iY+16)
```